# Cron job running successfully but nothing happens

Tags: python, linux, cron

I am very new to creating cron jobs and the linux environment in general, so apologies in advance if the questions sound too simple. I will try to present my problem as clearly as possible. So here it goes,

I have created a simple email (sending to myself) script using Python(3.5.2 version) and I want to schedule this script to run every 2 minutes using the cron job scheduling. I am logging into a remote linux server using SSH where my Python script is stored. The script runs perfectly fine when I run it manually using the linux terminal. When I try to schedule a cron job schedule for this script, my guess is that the script runs, because I can see runs in the  logs using

```
sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

What I see in the logs is something like this

```
Dec 30 19:38:01 abc-abcStation CRON[18707]: (abc) CMD (/home/abc/anuj/TPA/Test_Cron.py)
```

at an interval of 2 mins

But the run is not doing what it is supposed to do (send an email), which it does when I run it manually. My cron job looks like this

```
*/2 * * * * /home/abc/anuj/TPA/Test_Cron.py
```

The email sending script is Test_Cron.py which looks like this

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("username@mycompany.com", "mypassword")

msg = "TEST MESSAGE!"
server.sendmail("username@mycompany.com", "myemail@mycompany.com", msg)
server.quit()
```

I searched quite a lot for this kind of an issue and found similar cases to myself, tried all of the suggested solutions but I'm still missing something.

My guess is that this has something to do with setting the right path. I tried setting the path above my crontab statement, something like

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
*/2 * * * * /home/abc/anuj/TPA/Test_Cron.py
```

Also tried,

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
*/2 * * * * /home/abc/anuj/TPA/Test_Cron.py
```

and,

```
*/2 * * * *  cd /home/abc/anuj/TPA/ && Test_Cron.py
```

but no success. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not trying to add "source ~/.bash_profile" above your crontab statement to reduce the difference between the crontab script and your manually run?

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll help, but have you added `#/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your `Test_Cron.py` file (to let Linux know that it has to be run with Python) and given it execution permissions? (just for testing, do `chmod a+x /home/abc/anuj/TPA/Test_Cron.py` on a terminal... ) Either that, or change your `crontab` entry to `*/2 * * * * python /home/abc/anuj/TPA/Test_Cron.py` (see the `python`? In that entry, the "program" to run is `python` that will try to run `Test_Cron.py`)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @BorrajaX, thanks for responding, your suggestion */2 * * * * python /home/abc/anuj/TPA/Test_Cron.py worked for the file Test_Cron.py, however when I tried to do the same for another python script within the same folder, it did not work. So I have two Python scripts within the same folder Test_Cron.py and abc.py, abc.py works fine when run independently as well. I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: @jww, thanks for letting me know, I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: I tried that but my crontab does'nt execute if I do that, it gives me an error message '/tmp/crontab.ljDVOB/crontab":23: bad minute errors in crontab file, can't install'

Comment: @BorrajaX, I tried your suggestion to add #/usr/bin/env python at the top of my abc.py code, as well as  #!/usr/bin/python but no success.

Answer (score 0):

If this at all helps I had the same exact case but I found that since I'm using different conda environments to code my scripts;I had to specify via the shebang #! the path to my python interpreter for the env i used to code the script within the script.

That made it work. I also had another script running just fine otherwise when calling it with the "python3" command via the cron job.

I only surmise that some modules probably weren't loading correctly and it failed without even writing any output.

Get your conda envs path

```
    conda info --envs
```

Add this to the top of your script and simply supply the path in a cron job.

```
    #!/home/username/anaconda3/envs/AutoBrowsing/bin/python
```

Example Cronjob:

```
    */6 * * * * /home/username/path/to/script.py >> /home/username/scriptlog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Tried EVERYTHING in this post. I only figured out the problem because of [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/137468/better-logging-for-cronjobs-send-cron-output-to-syslog)

I sent output to logger to redirect output to syslog, as I didn't want to deal with linux mail. Here is the command I ran in `crontab -e`

`*/1 * * * * /home/me/backup 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -t CRON[backup_output]`

Doing this now showed the commands output in `/var/log/syslog`. What I found was `/bin/bash: me: command not found`.

This was happening because I still had the username in my crontab file. User automation must be removed when using `crontab -e`. Adding a username should be added to cronjobs placed in `/etc/cron.d/`. So, solution? Remove the username in your cronjob. So just put the frequency it should run, and the script thats it.